# Is there any way to set the first result of deltas to 0?

Tags: dolphindb

Is there any way to set the first result of deltas to 0?
The first parameter of the deltas result is a null value. Is there any way to set it to be 0?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is vague, consider providing additional details and a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

The first element of the result obtained by the deltas function is always NULL, You can see the details for the function [deltas](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/d/deltas.html).

Use the higher order function [eachPre](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Functionalprogramming/TemplateFunctions/eachPre.html) can solve your problem:

```py
x=1..10; eachPre(-,x,x[0])
```

The result is:

```py
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```